# How to nest multi-module maven projects in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My project structure looks like this:

```
services
  A
    a1
    a2
    pom.xml
  B
    b1
    b2
    pom.xml 
  pom.xml
```

I would like to scan the inner-most projects (`a1`,`a2`,`b1`,`b2`). In jenkins Post Steps, I added "Analysis properties" in Execute SonarQube Scanner without property files, mainly:

```
sonar.modules=A,B  
sonar.sources=src
```

I would like to build from services directory, but it failed with this ERROR:

> The folder 'src' does not exist for 'A:a1'

I understand, that SonarQube tries to find `src` inside the directory `A`, but I have a few nested projects like `a1` (I also tried `A.modules=a1,a2` without success)

How can I make the scanner analyze these projects?

Comment: From this question it's not clear why you cannot use simply `mvn sonar:sonar`. That should analyze the entire project with all sub-modules without any additional configuration. You don't need to edit `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`, this should work out of the box. Can you tell me what is missing when you analyze using `mvn sonar:sonar` ?

Comment: @ janos  ,I misunderstood mvn sonar:sonar indeed, I found it's rather convenient than properties. But it needs config  sonar in settings.xml like @slartidan referred documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is my solution:

```
sonar.modules=A,B 
A.sonar.modules=a1,a2
B.sonar.modules=b1,b2
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sources=src
```

the key point is projectBaseDir ,I hope this can help someone meet the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven goal `sonar:sonar` instead of a `sonar.properties` configuration, when analyzing maven projects with SonarQube.

You should not even have to change any analysis property, when using maven. The maven configuration will already give sonar information about source folders, etc. Check [the official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) on how to set it up. Usually you do not have to change the pom.xml of the projects for this (only you local maven `settings.xml`).

Comment: Do you mean add dependency in pom? I don't like to modify someone's project. Is there anyway just edit "Analysis properties" ?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I don't like to edit settings.xml either. I finally figure out a way ,see my answer .